# Different user views same object or different object?

Tags: uml, ooad

Let's say I have an web app that have two user. The applicant sends in the application form, and the case handler process the application. Different users have different views of the application form. Physically, it might be the same application form. But in the electronic processing, they can be regarded as different object that has dependent association. My question is what factors shall be taken into consideration to make the decision, whether use one application class or separate them into two classes, one for application form, one for case form. My take on this is that both users have their own operations on the object and they don't "share" the same operation. Creating two class diagrams might make more sense that each class has clear responsibility, but I need to create new classes for every subclasses of the application form classes and that will be a lot of classes. 
[image: An UML class diagram illustration:]

Comment: Please add uml diagrams to show the different options. That will make it much easier to get useful answers.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I have added the UML diagrams

Comment: I fail to see how using different diagrams will duplicate your classes. You can still make two diagrams with different views on the same classes no?

Comment: Class ATypeApplication and ATypeCase are the same class (same attributes, same operation) but different views. What do you mean by "make two diagrams with different views on the same classes"?

Comment: You can surely make two (or more) diagram that show the same classes can't you? If your UML tool won't allow that then it's time to look for a better tool.

Comment: The main idea is that you make a model of UML element, packages, connectors, properties, etc.. Diagrams are only used to provide a view upon that model. Sort of like a window to a house. Your kitchen can have different windows, showing different sides of the kitchen sink, but you only have one sink in the kitchen.

Comment: The application can be modeled as one class, but it can also be separated into two classes, one for case, one for application. In that case, it's not the same "sink".

Comment: Ok, so your question is: How to decide whether or not to separate the application class into two classes: Application and Case. Maybe you should reword your question to make that clear.

Comment: @ Geert Bellekens That's right. What's your opinion on this?

Comment: @KevinQ: if they are two different concepts to someone who is an expert in the domain, you should almost always separate them.

Answer (score 0):

Your second model makes a semantic split against the first one, separating `Case` from `Application`. Then you create specializations of either. That does not seem to make sense. Your split would make sense mainly if the reason was a re-use of e.g. the same `Application` and specialize just `Case` or vice versa:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like your Model2 diagram, although there are a few things you can do to make it better. Your diagram already makes it clear that in the problem domain, an `ATypeApplication` initiates only an `ATypeCase`, and a `BTypeApplication` initiates only a `BTypeCase`.

What I would do to improve the diagram is:

- Consider using optional multiplicity. Does an application always have an associated case? (How about before it's submitted?)
- Add association-end properties to the three associations, like

  ```
  |Application|--initiated by [1]----------initiates [0..1]--|Case|
  ```

  (Sorry for the pidgin UML, I don't feel like firing up my UML tool and finding a place to host the graphic.)
- Use `{redefines}` on the association ends of the associations between subclasses to make it clear that you are further constraining the type of each property.